# Accessing value of wp_customize setting

Tags: wordpress

So, I've got the following code:

```
    function themename_customize_register($wp_customize){

        // Display date
        $wp_customize->add_section('display_date_section', array(
            'title'    => 'Datum weergeven',
            'description' => 'Wil je de datum weergeven?',
            'priority' => 120,
        ));

        $wp_customize->add_setting('display_date', array(
            'default'        => 'value1',
            'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
            'type'           => 'option',
        ));

        $wp_customize->add_control('display_date_section', array(
            'label'      => 'Datum weergeven:',
            'section'    => 'display_date_section',
            'settings'   => 'display_date',
            'type'       => 'theme_mod',
            'choices'    => array(
                'value1' => 'Ja',
                'value2' => 'Nee',
            ),
        ));
    }


add_action('customize_register', 'themename_customize_register');
```

How can I access the value of the setting? Right now whenever I try to access it (either through `get_theme_mod` or `$wp_customize->get_settings`) My main goal with the code is to let users have the ability to control wether they want to display the date or not. Can somebody help me? :D